# $_GET not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, get

i have a code in which i received two variable($isbn,$eno) from former page via form GET method but these two variables are not working if i am not echo out it on my page the code for the same is given below.

```
                <?php
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            require 'db/connect.php';
            if(isset($_POST['generatereport']))
            {
                $isbn=$_GET['isbn'];
                $eno=$_GET['eno'];
                echo $eno;    //if this is not done then i am  not receiving data from database
                echo $isbn;   //if this is not done then i am not receiving data from database

                $studentdata="select * from users where eno='$eno'";
                if($studentresult=$db->query($studentdata))
                {
                    $studentrow = $studentresult->fetch_assoc();
                }
                else
                {
                    echo"fetching error";
                }
                $bookdata="select Lpad(isbn,'10','0') as isbn,book_name from book_data where isbn='$isbn'";
                if($bookresult=$db->query($bookdata))
                {
                    $bookrow = $bookresult->fetch_assoc();
                }
                else
                {
                    echo"fetching error";
                }


            }
            ?>
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang='en'>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div id='report'>
            <table>
            <tr><td><h3>Issue Report</h3></td></tr>
            <tr><td><h4>Student details</h4></td></tr>
            <tr><td>UNIQUE ID:<?php //random number here ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Enrollment:<?php echo $eno; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Name:<?php echo strtoupper($studentrow['fname']);echo strtoupper( $studentrow['lname']); ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Branch:<?php echo strtoupper($studentrow['branch']); ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Semester:<?php echo $studentrow['sem']; ?></td></tr>
            </table>
            <hr/>
            <table>
            <tr><td><h4>Book details</h4></td></tr>
            <tr><td>isbn:<?php echo $bookrow['isbn']; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Book Name:<?php echo strtoupper($bookrow['book_name']);?></td></tr>
            </table>
            <hr/>
            <form action="script/issue.php?isbn=<?php echo $isbn;?>" method='post' id='report'>
            <input id="btn_issue" type="button" value="Issue this Book"/>
            <input id="btn_close" type="button" value="cancel"/>
            </form>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: your form method is `post`. change it to `get`

Comment: You're checking `isset($_POST..` and then try to read from `$_GET`...

Comment: Be careful. Your code is a call for mysql injection.

Comment: As @HarryFink already said, your script is vulnerable to SQL injections; you should read on [how to prevent them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: I know how to use mysqli_real_escape_string method for submiting data and preventing sql injection but as this was just sample code i hadn't included it

Answer (score 3):

You need to set attribute `name` to inputs in your form, after that you can access to value by `GET` or `POST`
Change form method:

```
  <form action="script/issue.php?isbn=<?php echo $isbn;?>" method='get' id='report'>
                <input name ='isbn' id="btn_issue" type="button" value="Issue this Book"/>
                <input name ='eno' id="btn_close" type="button" value="cancel"/>
  </form>
```

Or get your variables from post, like:

```
  $isbn=$_POST['isbn'];
 $eno=$_POST['eno'];
```

Answer (score 1):

change your from method to `get`

```
<form action="script/issue.php?isbn=<?php echo $isbn;?>" method='get' id='report'>
```

or you can use `$_REQUEST` in php which can read either `get` or post

Answer (score 0):

If you use `method="POST"`, it meant you should use `$_POST` for your next process. Can use `$_REQUEST` also. But I think `$_POST` is more specifics for method `POST`. Please read the documentation of PHP about form method again.